# Generate Two Random Numbers for RANSAC sampling

Tags: c, random

I have looked at how to generate two random ints with rand()%n (where n is the total number of samples) but they seem to usually have a bias.

Is there a better (and preferably simpler) way to generate random numbers between 0 and n (number of samples)?

n is read from a file which contains a list of data points. The goal is to do a line fitting through the data using RANSAC.

Comment: As Akku mentioned rand() has some problems.  What OS are you on?  There are some OS that have better PRNG's than rand.

Comment: Also, how significant is the bias, and for which values of n do you observe this bias?

Comment: I'm on OS X. I don't know how significant the bias was - except it kept repeating the numbers near the upper end i.e. if n was 10 it would put numbers greater then 5 more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rand() % n` uses only the low bits of the random number when `n` is significantly smaller than `RAND_MAX`. It's better to use all of the bits e.g. by dividing by `RAND_MAX` to get a (floating point) number between 0.0 and 1.0 and then multiplying by *n* and converting back to an integer.

It is also possible that the implementation of `rand()` is simply not good enough for some uses. In this case use another random number generator altogether (e.g. Mersenne Twister).

Comment: Except for the first sentence this is a good answer. Your first sentence is only true when `n` is power of 2. Which it might be sometimes.